# Samsung laptop won't boot past Samsung screen to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi

I have a Samsung Laptop, model NP355V5C.

It turns on, shows the Samsung logo does some loading, then shows a black screen.

I have changed firmware settings to disable secure boot and to allow UEFI and Legacy OS. I have set the DVD drive as first priority in boot.

I have inserted a Windows 8.1 DVD and it still won't boot from it.  I tried the CD in 2 other laptops, and 1 desktop (all Windows 7) and it worked without issue.

Currently downloading the repair CD for Windows, but I have no idea if its a 32 or 64 bit system. Is there any way to tell it from the UEFI?

The reason I'm trying to boot from CD is because at times I will get past the Samsung screen, only for the screen to give me an error message about "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD"  and to restart with the repair CD. Of course the repair CD didn't come with the computer, so I'm using a Windows 8.1 install DVD, but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. the NP355V5C is 6-bit and ships with 64-bit Windows 8; see [Samsung's specs](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP355V5C-S01US-specs).
2. You need to *disable* UEFI (i.e. *enable* CSM mode) as well as *enable* Legacy mode and change the boot order. Samsung has a guide to [downgrading to Windows 7](http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=415842&modelname=NP350V5C), which shows how to boot from alternate media. See also [How to Boot from a USB](https://craftedflash.com/info/how-boot-computer-from-usb-flash-drive), most of which also applies to CD.